# Zend Form Decorators add classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm new to Zend, and beginner in php. I have a form generating several Elements. I have already add Decorators to have each of them in a div :

```
$element->addFilter('StringTrim')->addDecorators(array('clearfix'=>new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'clearfix'))));
```

My generated html looks like that :

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="optional">Email</label></dt>
        <dd id="email-element">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text" maxlength="100">    
        </dd> 
    </div>
```

I want to add a class to the dd tag to have that :

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        <dt id="email-label"><label for="email" class="optional">Email</label></dt>
        <dd class="clearfix" id="email-element">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text" maxlength="100">    
        </dd> 
    </div>
```

EDIT :

```
/* ###################################  email                ################################### */
    $email          = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email          ->setLabel("Email");
    $email          ->setAttrib('class','text');
 // $email          ->setRequired(true);
    $email          ->addValidator('EmailAddress');
    $email          ->setFilters(array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'));
    $email          ->addFilter('StringTrim')->addDecorators(array('clearfix'=>new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag'=>'div','class'=>'clearfix'))));
    $email          ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(0, 100));
    $email          ->setAttrib('maxlength', '100');
    $this           ->addElement($email);
```

Someone have an idea ? 
Thanks!

Comment: can you post your whole form?

Comment: It's a long form, i edit and add the element part ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email'); 
$element->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'yourclass' )));
```

Comment: It works but it delete the 'id' so i add it like that         $email          ->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'clearfix', 'id' => 'email-element' ))));
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$deco_html_tag = $element->getDecorator('HtmlTag');
$deco_html_tag->setOption('class', 'clearfix');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way without using the decorators.

You can add this in your form class.

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
       'ViewHelper'
));
```

And render your form like this in your view.

```
<form class="your-class" id="<?php echo $this->form->getAttrib('id'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->form->getAttrib('name'); ?>" action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->form->getAction()); ?>" method="<?php echo $this->escape($this->form->getMethod()); ?>">

<div class="something"> 
     <?php echo $this->form->getElement('element')->getLabel();  ?>
</div>
<div class="something"> 
     <?php echo $this->form->getElement('element');  ?>
</div>
</form?
```

Comment: @lovis91 Glad to be of help.